# Find nth Palindrome Number

Tags: java, palindrome

I want to find nth palindromic number and I try to with `ArrayList`  actually working and finding `nth` palindrome but too slowly working How can I do without `arraylist`?  or How can I do better?

```
(1 -- is the first)
(2 -- is the second)
(3 -- is the third)
.....
(9 -- is the Ninth.)
(11 -- is the 10th)
(22-- is the 11th)
(919---is the hundredth)
 .....so on
```

the code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = Integer.parseInt(cin.nextLine());

    ArrayList<Integer> str = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <=10000000; i++) {
        if(str.size()==10000){break;}
        int a = i;
        int b = inverse(a);
        if (a == b) {
            str.add(a);
        }

    }
    do {

        int y = str.get(num - 1);
        System.out.println(y);



    } while (num==0);

}

public static int inverse(int x) {
    int inv = 0;
    while (x > 0) {
        inv = inv * 10 + x % 10;
        x = x / 10;

    }
    return inv;
}
}
```

Comment: What about `if (str.size() == num)` instead?

Comment: This is a math problem, not a programming problem. Find a way to find the nth palindrome without having to find all earlier palindromes.

Comment: Looping to 10000000 is always going to take a while.

Comment: To add to what Eric has said - Consider that for every palindrome the left half of it (Including the middle for odd lengths) is enough to determine the whole thing and is also enough to determine their ordering.

Comment: Break down the problem.  All 1-digit numbers are palindromes.  If you were asked to find the Nth 2-digit palindrome (the first is 11), how would you do it?  If you were asked to find the Nth 3-digit palindrome (the first being 101), how could you do that?  Try listing the first dozen and see if you can figure out what the pattern is.  Then look at 4-digit palindromes, etc.  Finally, once you figure out how many there are of each, you can start by determining whether the Nth palindrome is 2, 3, 4, etc. digits, so you know how many shorter numbers to skip.

Comment: In fact - since you already have the machinery in place, you should do some exploring - For every length of the palinfrom, print some values from the start and end of that length range and their number in the sequence and it should become obvious

Comment: yes ı know tihs is math problem but I want to solve another way is possible?

Comment: I add 1 to 1000nth palindrome in arraylisrt and then ı take what ı want to from araylist @ajb

Comment: @Mercur I have no idea what you are trying to tell me.  But if you're using any kind of array or list of palindromes, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @ajb I told you my programing how ı find polindrome numbers in arraylist.I do not want to solve this problem ı just want to some algorithm better than from this.

Comment: @Eric exactly ı want to find without all earlier palindromes but how can ı do can you tell me some algorithm?

Comment: just added in arraylist 1000nth palindrome@LuiggiMendoza

Answer (score 0):

Just use a counter variable to keep count of the ith palindrome.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = Integer.parseInt(cin.nextLine());
    int p = 0;


    for (int i = 1; i <=10000000; i++) {
        if(p==10000){break;}
        int a = i;
        int b = inverse(a);
        if (a == b) {
            p++;
            if(p==num)
            {
                System.out.println(a);
                break;
            }
        }

    }


}
```